# Saving YouTube-Title in Variable on MacOS

Tags: python, macos, terminal

I am trying to save the video title of a youtube video in a variable.

This is what I got so far:

```
import os

title = os.system('youtube-dl --get-filename -o "%(title)s.%(ext)s" '+url)
print(title)
```

Unfortunately, if I print the variable, it only returns 0.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that works well for me:

```
import os
import subprocess

url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7-qGKqveZaM"
title = subprocess.check_output('youtube-dl -e --get-title '+url, shell=True, universal_newlines=None)
```